# Cant connect to mqtt-broker because Mono.Unity.UnityTlsContext.ProcessHandshake

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ssl, mqtt

I'm using Unity and want to constantly receive mqtt-data that I can attach to a game object. So I'm trying to enable a connection like this:

```cs
async void testconnect()
    {

        const string server = "somewebadress.com";
        const string clientId = "Test";

        var caCert = new X509Certificate2(@"ca.crt");
        var clientCert = new X509Certificate2(@"cert.pfx", "test");

        var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = source.Token;

        var factory = new MqttFactory();
        var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();

        var mqttOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
            .WithTcpServer(server, 8883)
            .WithClientId(clientId)
            .WithTls(new MqttClientOptionsBuilderTlsParameters
            {
                UseTls = true,
                AllowUntrustedCertificates = true,
                Certificates = new List<X509Certificate> { caCert, clientCert }
            })
            .Build();

        mqttClient.ConnectAsync(mqttOptions, token).Wait(token);
    }
```

But I'm receiving the following exception:

> NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

```
Mono.Unity.UnityTlsContext.ProcessHandshake ()
```

I've tried to find it out by myself, but I have no clue how to implement the `ProcessHandshake()` function.

Comment: Sounds related to [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2017-1-tls-1-2-still-not-working-with-net-4-6.487415/) .. which Unity version are you using and what is your target platform?